# MongoDB $set changing datatypes

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB 3.2 instance running on Ubuntu 14.04. Single node set up. Last night I performed a migration where I ran this code for ~1400 documents in a collection:

```
for r in responses: # find cursor with ~1400 documents in it
    database.responses.update_one({
        "_id" : r["_id"]
    }, {
        "$set" : {
            "client_id" : client["_id"]
        }
    })
```

After the migration, some of the fields in my response documents in the `responses` collection had switched from `DateObject` types to `Int32` timestamp representations. Some of the `Int32` fields had changed to `Double`s. These fields were not updated in my `$set` statement (obviously). **This affected only a small subset of the cursor (~75 documents).**

This caused catastrophic failure as our models expected those fields to have data types they no longer had. Can someone explain to me what went wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

after reading your question I got curious to know what went wrong, I guess if you have explicitly sat your type in the creation/update of these record you would not have faced that issue, for example:-

```
for r in responses: # find cursor with ~1400 documents in it
database.responses.update_one({
    "_id" : r["_id"]
}, {
    "$set" : {
        "client_id" : new DateObject(client["_id"]);
    }
})
```

Comment: `client_id` is already of ObjectId type and was not one of the fields affected, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that somewhere else in your code python has made changes in the types (maybe some code that is trying to automatically infer the type !?).

I am pretty sure that before your "for r in responses: " code there is something else that is maybe trying to detect the type of the fields. Is this the case? Can you provide the code before the snippet you provided ?

Comment: It could be Pymongo, the MongoDB library I'm using, but it's never done this before... The objects in the `responses` list is a cursor object with Pymongo results (BSON dicts)